# Mac address clone on DD-WRT

Tags: dd-wrt, isp, mac-address

I am on a network on which I have my old router's mac address registered so I can access the internet through this network (it's filtered by mac address).

I've recently replaced the old router and am running DD-WRT on my new router. On [this](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/MAC_Address_Clone) page of the DD-WRT wiki it says that the "mac adress clone" option should enable you to easily replace a router in this kind of a setup. Just clone your old mac address and you're done.

However, I've tried this and it doesn't work for me. As soon as I connect the new router (with the cloned mac address), I'm rerouted to a captive portal and cannot access the internet. I can also see that other computers on the network are connecting to my router (I don't know if that's normal).

Does anyone know why this doesn't work as advertised? Is the "mac address clone" not changing the mac address as it should, or are there any other options I have to configure as well? (I know this is a very general question, but I'm just not very sure where to begin, or what information to provide)

Comment: is your DDWRT connected over an LAN-Cable with your isp-router (not a bridge/repeater over wlan or something)? and which interface on the ddwrt did you use? btw: which router are you using with ddwrt

Comment: Why don't you just registered the new router with your ISP?  This is far to localized, and far to many questions need to be answered, can't really be answered.

Comment: @Cadburry, yeah it's connected with a lan cable, but I don't really know the exact layout of the network. I believe it connects to a router (which might act as a bridge or something), which then connects to the main router that routes traffic to the www. And I'm using a TP-Link WR740N. (and I don't know what you mean by interface, sorry)

Comment: @Samuel Does it work when you connect your computer/notebook directly with your isp's router? (changing the MAC on your client!)
(interface > is your LAN cable pluged into the "blue" socket on your TP-Link and not into one of the yellow ones)

Comment: @Cadburry, yeah the lan cable is connected to the blue (wan) port, and my computers are connected to the yellow ports. And I can't connect to the www (or the network) when I plug the cable directly into my laptop, as my laptops mac address isn't registered (and I don't know how to change it).

Comment: @Samuel, do you use Windows? If yes then: Right klick on computer - select manage - hardware - locate your network adapter (rightklick) properties - tab advanced - and in the list there should be a member like "local address" or MAC or something...

Comment: @Cadburry, yeah I do, and I can find the mac address. But this dialog doesn't allow me to change it, so I can't directly access the network with it, because the mac address isn't registered with my isp.

Comment: @Samuel ...ok by changeing the mac on the PC you could find out whether the problem is the router or it is a general problem..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution was to use mac clone, apply changes, and then turn the router off and on again. Apparently only then does the mac address change.

After that everything works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

What's being cloned here is the MAC address of the PC you're using to access the router, not the MAC address of the old router. Your new router has no way determining your old router's MAC address.

I guess you could clone your old router's MAC address if you connected to your new router *through* your old router. Then the MAC address the new router sees is that of the old router instead of that of your PC. Tricky, though. Might be easier just to enter the MAC address by hand.

If you no longer have the old router and haven't recorded its MAC address somewhere, then there's no way to get it into the new router. You'll just have get the network administrator to add the new MAC address to the filter list.

Comment: I manually entered the old mac address. Which is why I'm so surprised that it doesn't work.

Comment: Did you maybe clone your PC address onto the old router? That would mean your PCs Mac address with be the one the network knows about.

Comment: No, I cloned the registered mac address, which is the old router's mac address. So I'm sure that it's the right one. So it should work..